# Ton of leaks in [SBJsonParser scanRestOfDictionary:]

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, instruments

I got a ton of leaks in [SBJsonParser scanRestOfDictionary:] (# > 2000). I have no idea where to look in the code. Any suggestions would be very appriciated!

Thanks

Edit:

I updated to JSONKit. Still get leaks:

[image]

Comment: ARC better be the first place...

Comment: What does "Analyze" says (Shift+cmd+b) ?

Comment: hmm... Couldn't solve the problem with that :(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem some time ago, and the only solution I found was switching to another JSON library. Now I use JSONKit, which has better performance, and no leaks (or, I did not see any...). Here is the [library](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit).